# find d square no.?

Tags: c

```
int n=16;

for(i=0;i<=n;i++) {
  if(n/i==i) {
    printf("its a square no");

  }
  else
    printf("not a square no.");
```

i want to print one statement neither else statement nor if statement.... but output getting not a prime 3 time and prime no one time again...

help me

output for n=16 and n=15

Comment: Note that integer division might not be what you want: 17/4 = 4, so 17 is a square!?

Answer (score 3):

In your code you would also to test that the remainder is 0:

```
((n/i==i) && (n%i==0))
```

**EDIT**

As Sjoerd pointed out, I was being particularly bone-headed and you may as well just test `i*i==n` as so:

```
bool perfect(int n)
{
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        if (i*i==n)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

I realise that this is C++ but you get the picture!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
int n=16;
for(i=0;1<=n;i++)
```

should be

```
float n=16.0;
for(float i=1.0;i<=n;i++)
```

i=1.0 as you shouldn't divide by zero

you could use found_square=1 when you are successful, and possibly use another if/else statement to print if n is a square, depending on the value of found_square.

also you may like to add a break command following your successful case. As soon as you succeed, there would be no need to continue within the for loop.

Comment: Wow, a for loop with a floating point loop variable. Never seen that before!! I remain unconvinced of its wisdom. Better to run the loop over and integer and convert to float inside the loop body if that's what you want. Or use `%` and avoid float altogether.

Comment: or just compare n against i*i. Multiplying is faster than division anyway.